# Java: Getting JPEG DCT coefficients histogram

Tags: java, jpeg, histogram, dct

I need a Java library, code snippet,... to get the Frequency distribution of the
64 DCT coefficients of a JPEG file.

Any ideas? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the distribution of a particular file then you can try to convert it into bmp and use my code provided in my question:

[Decompression stops inbetween and output file filled with zeros(BLACK PIXELS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339118/uncompression-stops-inbetween-and-output-file-filled-with-zerosblack-pixels)

You may need to weak it to work with java. The idea is store all 64 coeff in an array for each 8*8 block. Then count the frequency of each value for each coeff no such as 0,0(DC) or 0,1 or 8,8(highest freq) and plot the frequency in y-axis and value in x-axis. you will get 64 plots, one for each coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no simple answer to directly getting the DCT coefficients from a JPEG file. Decompressing the image and re-applying the DCT transform is a reasonable approximation, but it does tend to introduce rounding errors.

The only solution I found to getting the JPEG coefficients directly from the file was to use JNA to connect to the native JPEG library. You asked for a library or code snippet. I have written a Java library that should meet your needs. My code is very crude but can be easily extended. Here: https://github.com/markzampoglou/dct-extraction